# Java:The child class implement interface, but the parent class override the members of the interface?

Tags: java, android, interface

Typically, a class implements an interface, and the class itself or its child class override the methods in the interface, such as:

Define an interface:

```
interface Interface {
    void fun();
}
```

1.Parent class override the interface method, and child class direct inherit:

```
public class Parent implements Interface{
    public void fun(){
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
}
```

Or:

2.The parent class is defined as an abstract class and the child class override the methods in the interface:

```
public abstract class Parent implements Interface{
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public void fun(){
    }
}
```

However, I also see a strange way to override the interface method:

3.The child class only implement interfaces, but override methods in the interface by the parent class:

```
public class Parent{
    public void fun(){
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent implements Interface{
}
```

The third way to override the interface method is very common in the android framework source code, for example:

```
public interface ViewParent {
    //......
    void requestLayout();
    ViewParent getParent();
}

public class View implements Drawable.Callback, KeyEvent.Callback, AccessibilityEventSource {
    //......
    @CallSuper
    public void requestLayout() {
        //......
    }

    public final ViewParent getParent() {
        return mParent;
    }
}

public abstract class ViewGroup extends View implements ViewParent, ViewManager {
    //......
}
```

The method **requestLayout()** and **getParent()** comes from **ViewParent**, and **ViewGroup implements ViewParent**, but why does the implementation of the method be done in the parent class **View**?

What is the reason for this design?

Comment: What is the reason why it shouldn't be allowed?

Comment: Your 3rd point doesn't match with the example you have given.(Parent doesn't implement Interface in the Android example and that's perfectly normal) Correct your question.

Comment: @pulp_fiction The core of the question is:Subclass implements an interface，but the Super class override methods of the interface. In the example, the focus is on the relationship between ViewParent, View and ViewGroup. This relative relationship is consistent with the third design pattern.

Comment: I am afraid, your example is **wrong** in the context! Not even the relative relationship you are talking about. See: `public class View extends Object implements` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: As you can see View extends Object!!!

Comment: @pulp_fiction Aha, in java, every object extends the Object class. so In the javadoc documents, there will exist "extends Object". But in the source code, "extends Object" is usually omitted. You can see the source code:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java. Also, the Object class does not affect the relationship mentioned above.

Comment: But an Interface **doesn't** extend Object. Your hierarchy involves a **common** interface. Both base and child extend that interface. In Android example, View doesn't implement the ViewParent interface!! See properly before commenting please!

Comment: @pulp_fiction May be my English is not good, so I can not fully understand your meaning. On the 3rd point, I did not see in essence with the following examples of android source code is different. Although, View implements some interfaces, but these interfaces are not included requestLayout() and getParent(). Therefore, these unrelated interfaces can even omit not write, so that more prominent themes.This is only to keep the source code consistent, so only to write those irrelevant interfaces, they will not affect the relative relationship between the View, ViewGroup and ViewParent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, every `View` has a parent `View`, so the base `View` class needs a `getParent()` method and has a `mParent` property.

However, `View` doesn't implement `ViewParent`, since not all views are parents of other views.

If `View` was implementing some basic "ViewInterface", it would be possible to include `getParent()` in that interface, but since it doesn't, `getParent()` was included in the `ViewParent` interface.

And since `View` already implements that method, the `ViewGroup` sub-class doesn't have to implement it.

Comment: Your answer is around the example he has posted. The real question is, why a pattern like, `Parent implements Interface` and `Base extends Parent implements Interface` is acceptable? This is also found in Standard Java APIs